# Load a set of variables from a SQL database - language ASP.NET VB

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server, vb.net, variables

I am trying to translate an old "Classic ASP" page to ASP.NET page. I have limited ASP.NET knowledge.
I am reading some data from a SQL server.
I have a basic question, but so far I was not able to successfully implement any working solution.

The code attached is working well;  shows the data I need.
I would like to have a similar code structure but this time I would like to assign the data from SQL to variables (I do not need to print these output values on the screen):

title (output of SQL query) --->  "titleV" variable (string)

father (output of SQL query) ---> "fatherV" variable (string)

age (output of SQL query) ---> "ageV" variable (number)

If possible, please suggest to me a piece of code I can test.
Thank you.

```
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Data.OleDb" %>
<script  runat="server">
sub Page_Load
dim dbconn,sql,dbcomm,dbread
dbconn=NewOleDbConnection("connection string to sql server")
dbconn.Open()
sql="SELECT * FROM photos"
dbcomm=New OleDbCommand(sql,dbconn)
dbread=dbcomm.ExecuteReader()
customers.DataSource=dbread
customers.DataBind()
dbread.Close()
dbconn.Close()
end sub
</script>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form runat="server">
<asp:DataList id="customers" runat="server">
<ItemTemplate>
<%#Container.DataItem("title")%>  in
<%#Container.DataItem("father")%> with
<%#Container.DataItem("age")%> years
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
</form>

</body></html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can save one record in above 3 variables because you are not using array type or collections. You can assign the data from the table to your variables using the following code.

```
sub page_load()
dbconn = new oledbconnection("conn str")
dbconn.Open()
sql="SELECT * FROM photos"
dim adpt as OledbDataAdapter
dim rs as new DataTable
adpt = new OledbDataAdapter(sql,dbconn)
adpt.fill(rs)
customers.DataSource = rs
customers.DataBind()

dim titleV, fatherV As String
dim ageV as integer

titleV = rs.Rows(0).Item(0)  'Rows(0).Item(0) gives you first row's first field value.
fatherV = rs.Rows(0).Item(1)
ageV = rs.Rows(0).Item(2)

dbconn.Close()
end sub
</script>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form runat="server">
<asp:DataList id="customers" runat="server">
<ItemTemplate>
<%#Container.DataItem("title")%>  in
<%#Container.DataItem("father")%> with
<%#Container.DataItem("age")%> years
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
</form>

</body></html>
```

Comment: Hello Vignesh, Thank you for the fast answer.BC30002: Type 'DataTable' is not defined.

Comment: Hello Vignesh, Thank you for the fast answer. I get the following error "Line 10: dim rs as new DataTable" BC30002: Type 'DataTable' is not defined.

Comment: "Type 'DataTable' is not defined" is solved using "dim rs as new System.Data.DataTable()"

Comment: A new error message come "Line 11: adpt=New OledbDataAdapter(sql,dbconn)" details:"BC30520: Argument matching parameter 'selectCommandText' narrows from 'Object' to 'String'". Any suggestion?

Comment: you have to pass select command as string and also connection object. Here sql is string variable having sql select command and dbconn is OleDbConnection.

Comment: make sure your connection string is proper and try by replacing sql by the "select query".

Comment: Vignesh, thank you. It works!!
Here there is the final code for public reference.
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Data.OleDb" %>
<%dim dbcomm,dbread
dim sql as string
dim dbconn = new oledbconnection("connstr")
dbconn.Open()
sql="SELECT * FROM photos"
dim adpt as OledbDataAdapter
dim rs as new System.Data.DataTable()
adpt = new OledbDataAdapter(sql,dbconn)
adpt.fill(rs)

dim titleV As String
dim fatherV As String

titleV = rs.Rows(0).Item(0)
fatherV = rs.Rows(0).Item(1)
dbconn.Close()
%>

<!DOCTYPE html><html><body>
title=<%=titleV%> <br>
father=<%=fatherV%> <br>
</body></html>